# .Net 6 with Ocelot 18 returns error 404 when navigating to an URL of the gateway after publish in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, .net-6.0, api-gateway, ocelot

I created a gateway with Ocelot and Net6, I configured the .json file and tested locally and everything works fine, but when I publish it to IIS it gives me a 404. When I go to the error it is setting the port to the route, or rather in the sub route.

I have a player microservice that is published in IIS and was also built with Net6 which I call without problem and it returns the data. When I try to call it from the gateway it doesn't work.

This is my .json file configuration

[image]

[image]

[image]

As can be seen in the image, the requested url is armed with the ports and I don't understand the reason.

Does anyone know the reason and can give me a hand to solve this issue.

I tried removing the ports and removing the BaseUrl but it always gives me the same error

Comment: You will have to edit the question to include more on how you deployed the gateway artifacts to the server, as that 404 error page indicates the URL didn't even initialize .NET runtime so that StateFile handler returns 404.

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, you can try to change the Application Pool from Classic to Integrated, you can also try removing and adding the service back in IIS, It might be an incorrect path for the service the cause for this error.